# C++ Automatically Censoring

Tags: java, c++, string, sockets

This is the most unusual thing I have ever encountered, I am making a game with a chatbox, so I was building a censor function, but I was having a lot of trouble although everything should have worked, so I tried debugging and I found out that if you set a string to a bad word (am I allowed to say them here?) And those words start with f, c, and p. (Take a guess which). So in the client (Java) you enter the message, and it will send it through the sockets (displayed the message RIGHT before the sending to the server (in C++), it displayed fine, but right after receiving the word in the server I displayed the message, and right after the first letter of a bad word you say, everything after is deleted.
I have no source to display because its not happening in the program?
Client Info:
Java, Netbeans default compiler
Server Info:
C++, Devcpp default compiler, it uses a mysql library and boost::algorithm/string, and boost:thread
I am on windows 7 Ultimate edition.

Some sources:
Java crypt function

```
public String crypt(String source)
{
    int len=source.length();
    String tempSource="";
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        String strAddon;
        int intAddon;
        char charAddon;
        charAddon=source.charAt(i);
        intAddon=127-((int)(charAddon));
        charAddon=(char)intAddon;
        strAddon=Character.toString(charAddon);
        tempSource+=strAddon;
    }
    source=tempSource;
    return source;
}
```

Java write function:

```
public void write(String text)
{
    try
    {
        text="|/" + text + "\\|";
        System.out.println(text);//debug
        text=crypt(text);
        out.println(text);
    }
    catch(Exception err)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(Sockets.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, err);
        closeSockets(1);
    }
}
```

C++ Crypt function

```
string crypt(string source)
{
    int len=source.length();
    char tempSource[len];
    source.copy(tempSource, len, 0);
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<len;i++) tempSource[i]=127-tempSource[i];
    source=tempSource;
    int temp=0;
    while((temp=source.find('\n',0)) != string::npos)
    {
        source=source.replace(temp,temp+1,"|");
        temp++;
    }
    return source;
}
```

C++ read function

```
string clientRead(int sock, string username)
{
    if(sock == INVALID_SOCKET) return "";
    vector<char> theVector;
    char responseData[256];
    char buffer;
    int bytesRead;

    memset(responseData, 0, sizeof(responseData));
    while(1)
    {
        bytesRead=recv(sock, &buffer, 1, 0);
        if(bytesRead > 0)//check to exit
        {
            if(buffer == '\n')
            {
                for(int i=0;i<theVector.size();i++) responseData[i]=theVector[i];
                string decryptedData=crypt(responseData);
                int beginIndex=decryptedData.find_first_of("|/")+2;
                if(beginIndex == -1) beginIndex=0;
                int endIndex=decryptedData.find("\\|");
                if(endIndex == -1) endIndex=decryptedData.length();
                decryptedData=decryptedData.substr(beginIndex, endIndex);
                cout<<decryptedData<<endl;//debug
                return decryptedData;
            }
            else theVector.push_back(buffer);
        }
        else//it failed
        {
            if(username.compare("") != 0) forceLogout(username);
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

the places marked debug is where i displayed the messages

Here is a video of it, WARNING, THERE ARE BAD WORDS IN IT
http://youtu.be/bSFT5YyAk9E
as you can see when i say the word with the f, it just breaks.

Comment: Wait, f, c, and p, but no s or a or anything?

Comment: You'll have to show us some example code, there's definitely a misuse of a string algorithm in there.

Comment: Did you perhaps censor the word by replacing it with NULL characters? ;-)

Comment: Has anyone besides me been trying to see how many offensive words they can come up with, using the given starting letters? =)

Comment: @paddy, I think I was in the wrong mindset for the first minute or two.

Comment: i did not replace them with null characters, but thank you

Comment: "This video is unavailable."